# How to add a job in crontab that can be executed with no priviledge restrict?

Tags: cron, permissions

```
*/5 * * * * root ./temp.sh
```

The above must be run as `root`,how to make it work for all users?

Answer (score 2):

add it to your global crontab in `/etc/crontab`

Answer (score 1):

```
su - 
crontab -e
```

Answer (score 0):

use sudo to run it and configure temp.sh in sudoers with the NOPASSWD option.